# Windows 7 background/desktop calendar

Tags: windows-7

Does this product exist?

The background of Windows desktop is now a calendar, displaying maybe a month or week view of my calendar. By pressing on days or appointments, I can quickly edit/add etc.

I basically want the month view from Outlook or Google Calendar as my windows interactive background.

Note that I am not looking for a sidebar gadget, or that desktop overlay program (rain-something?). :)

Does this product exist?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Rainlender](http://www.rainlendar.net/cms/index.php?option=com_rny_download&Itemid=32) can do something for you. It looks like this on desktop.

[image]

Also you can read this [article](http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/08/featured/7-google-calendar-desktop-clients.html) for more desktop calenders.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search brought me [Here](http://interactive-calendar.en.softonic.com/)

It may not be EXACTLY what you are looking for, but there may be some customization you can do to make it work for your needs!